# Parameters and links on react native

Tags: react-native, expo

How to add a link in the Expo.WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync(url) function. What I did Expo.WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync("{mylink}") and Expo.WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync({mylink}) does not work. What to do ? However, when I put Expo.WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync ("http://example.com"), it works well. Thanks for your help.

```
  renderPost = ({id, titre, contenu, mylink}, i) => {
    return (
      <View
        key={id}
        style={styles.post}
      >
        <View style={styles.postContent}>
          <Text>
            {titre}
          </Text>
          <Text style={styles.postBody}>
            {contenu}
          </Text>
          <Button
          style={styles.paragraph}
          title="Voir le site."
          onPress={() => Expo.WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync("{mylink}")}
          />
          <Text>{"\n\n"}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. The code:

```
  renderPost = ({id, titre, contenu, mylink}, i) => {
    return (
      <View
        key={id}
        style={styles.post}
      >
        <View style={styles.postContent}>
          <Text>
            {titre}
          </Text>
          <Text style={styles.postBody}>
            {contenu}
          </Text>
          <Button
          style={styles.paragraph}
          title="Voir le site."
          onPress={() => Expo.WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync(mylink)}
          />
          <Text>{"\n\n"}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
```